# 2d Array like datastruct with custum float index

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, internet-explorer-8

I want to create a datastructure with the characteristics of a 2d array(get specific items with 2 inputs for x and y) but not with normal int indexes in Javascript.

For example: I have an table like this:

```
x   200  250 370 500 ...
2   1023 234  22 243
2.5 2323 333 322 223
3.1  ...
...
```

and I want to get the output 322 with the help of the numbers 370, 2.5.

Whats the best way to code this?Are there existing datastructures, that I can use and maybe change a little or do I have to program something new? I couldn't find anything easy to use that cover my needs.

**It has to work in IE8**

**Edit**
The data is comming from an excelsheet.
The data has no "holes" so its a full block but some x-values have more y-values than others.(the higher x-values have more or the same amount of y-values never less)

Comment: 1) Are you writing for IE8 without a transpiler?
2) Will the table be sparse? Jagged? Or a full x*y table?
3) How will it be initialized, where is the data coming from?

Comment: 1)It would be easyer if it works without one in every browser but if needed i can use one2)The table is not full x*y some have more y than others but x are the same. 3)The data is comming from an excelsheet. The initialization is depending on the datastruct i think.

Comment: I'd say you should go with Nina Scholz's solution. Alternatively you may want to represent the whole table (including headers) as an array of arrays, with lookup objects having references to rows or just integer row numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a nested object with `x` values as key and nested `y` values. Access via

```
data[x][y]
```

```js
var data = {
        200: {
            2: 1023,
            2.5: 2323
        },
        250: {
            2: 234,
            2.5: 333
        },
        370: {
            2: 22,
            2.5: 322
        },
        500: {
            2: 243,
            2.5: 223
        }
    };


console.log(data[200][2.5]);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution could be to actually have the whole table, including or not including headers, in arrays, and then have a lookup object for rows or integer coordinates.

```
var table = [
  [ 'x', 200, 250 ]
  [ 2, 1023, 234 ]
]

var xlookup = { 2: table[1] }
// or
var xlookup = { 2: 1 }

var ytable = { 200: 1, 250: 2 }
```

Or without headers:

```
var table = [
  [ 1023, 234 ]
  [ 232, 333
]

var xlookup = { 2: table[0] }
// or
var xlookup = { 2: 0 }

var ytable = { 200: 0, 250: 1 }
```

This will allow you to easier iterate over the table, for example to render it.

Also, and this might be particularly important to IE8 users, it will prevent the duplication of ykeys such as 2 and 2.5, making the size in memory smaller.

Alternatively, with [Nina Scholz solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51810146/2115619) you could have arrays of keys to iterate over:

```
var data = {
        200: {
            2: 1023,
            2.5: 2323
        },
        250: {
            2: 234,
            2.5: 333
        },
        370: {
            2: 22,
            2.5: 322
        },
        500: {
            2: 243,
            2.5: 223
        }
    };

var xkeys = [ 200, 250, 370, 500 ]
var ykeys = [ 2, 2.5 ]
```